# Obtaining another page's data for a password-protected version in Wagtail

Tags: python, wagtail

I'm new to Python and Wagtail. I've got most of the way with the Wagtail site I'm working on, but am stuck on one issue.

The site is to show a set of products (plants) for retail (done and working) and the same set for trade with trade-only prices shown. I have `PlantIndexPage` and `PlantPage` Wagtail models, with the latter having various product fields and two price fields.

The trade price information should be password protected with [Wagtail's 'page privacy'](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/advanced_topics/privacy.html) password option, and so I believe I need a separate index page (`TradePlantIndexPage`) to which I can apply this page privacy setting in the Wagtail admin, to effectively contain its own trade versions of the public `PlantPage` product pages.

So I have many `PlantPage` pages (one for each plant product), and *one* `TradePlantPage` page using [`RoutablePageMixin`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) with a `@route` to accept the slug of any `PlantPage` product.

```py
# working: /plants/
class PlantIndexPage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['plants'] = Page.objects.exact_type(PlantPage).live().all().order_by('title')
        return context

# working, password protected: /trade/
class TradePlantIndexPage(PlantIndexPage):
    template = 'plants/plant_index_page.html'  # for PlantIndexPage and TradePlantIndexPage

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['trade'] = True  # condition in template depends on this to show trade prices
        return context

# working: /plants/<plant_page_slug>
class PlantPage(Page):
    price_retail = models.DecimalField(...)
    price_trade = models.DecimalField(...)
    # ...

# not yet working: /trade/plant/<plant_page_slug>
class TradePlantPage(RoutablePageMixin, PlantPage):
    parent_page_types = ['TradePlantIndexPage']
    subpage_types = []

    template = 'plants/plant_page.html'  # for PlantPage and TradePlantPage

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['trade'] = True  # condition in template depends on this to show trade price
        context['plant'] = Page.objects.page(???).live()  # how to get PlantPage by slug?
        return context

    @route(r'^([-\w]+)/$')
    def trade(self, request, plant_slug):
        self.trade = True
        # how to render TradePlantPage with PlantPage content based on plant_slug?
```

I'll have the `TradePlantIndexPage`'s list of plants link to the URL at which `TradePlantPage` is available (`/trade/plant/<plant_page_slug>`) instead of `PlantPage` (`/plants/<plant_page_slug>`).

For displaying a particular plant with `TradePlantPage`, how can I obtain the correct instance of `PlantPage` based on the `trade` `@route`'s `plant_slug`, and set the context so that the template for `PlantPage`, using the `page` variable, works?

I've appended comments/questions related to this in the code. Thanks.

---

### Update

Thanks to gasman's kind and easy to understand answer the trade route for `TradePlantPage` is now working. Following that answer's advice to use `plant` and not `page`, I have updated `PlantPage`'s context method to be:

```
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['trade'] = False
        context['plant'] = context['page']
        return context
```

This is working, but I wonder if `context['plant'] = context['page']` is a suboptimal way of being able to use `plant` instead of `page` in the shared template. I imagine it doubles the memory used for the field data, for example? Probably not an issue for this small site anyway, and I'll use it unless I hear otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `RoutablePageMixin` route method, the process of returning an HTTP response works the same way as in an ordinary Django view function - see [Django's 'Views and templates' tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/). The page's `template` property and `get_context` method are not used, unless you explicitly hook them up (and for the sake of simplicity, I'd suggest not doing that, and setting up the template and context variables directly in the method instead).

Your route method will need to do the following:

- Retrieve the correct `PlantPage` based on `plant_slug` - we'll use Django's `get_object_or_404` helper for this
- Render the template `plants/plant_page.html`, passing it the context variables `trade` (set to True), `plant` (set to the retrieved PlantPage) and `page` (set to the current page, i.e. the `TradePlantPage` object).

This gives us the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

class TradePlantPage(RoutablePageMixin, PlantPage):
    parent_page_types = ['TradePlantIndexPage']
    subpage_types = []

    @route(r'^([-\w]+)/$')
    def trade(self, request, plant_slug):
        plant = get_object_or_404(PlantPage, slug=plant_slug)

        return render(request, 'plants/plant_page.html', {
            'trade': True,
            'plant': plant,
            'page': self,
        })
```

Note: here I'm assuming that your `plant_page.html` template is set up to expect the variable `plant` when called from both `PlantPage` and `TradePlantPage` - e.g. you're using `{{ plant.title }}` rather than `{{ page.title }}` to output the plant name. If this isn't the case, it's probably OK to pass the `PlantPage` object as `page`, by setting `'page': plant,` in the code above. However, I'd suggest it's a good idea to give the template access to the 'real' page object currently being rendered - so that you can highlight the right item in your site navigation, for example.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and spelling everything out so clearly! I've updated my question with a minor, secondary question about using `plant` instead of `page`, in case I'm doing it wrong. :)

Comment: `context['plant'] = context['page']` is fine - it results in two variables pointing to the same object, so no field data gets copied. (You can confirm this by setting `context['plant'].title = 'new title'`, and seeing that `context['page'].title` is updated too.)